# Can a Google Shared Drive be indexed by Windows Indexing?

Tags: indexing, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I have a windows application that uses the `Dir` function to search for an item in a folder like this:

```
If Dir("X:\Maps\" & MapNum & ".jpg") <> "" Then
    Me![myMap].Picture = "X:\Maps\" & MapNum & ".jpg"
Else
    Me![myMap].Picture = "X:\Maps\NoMap.jpg"
End If
```

This works very fast because the Windows Indexing service is able to index the contents of the local disk.  Now I need to replace the local disk with a Google Shared disk.  This works, but very slowly because the content on the network disk is not indexed.

Google `Drive for desktop` has the option to mirror the files and store them both in the cloud and on my computer, thereby allowing them to be indexed.  I am trying to avoid having to store files on my computer if they already exist in the cloud. I would prefer to be able search against an index of the cloud files, but I don't know if that is possible.

Is it possible for a Windows Server to index the contents of a Google Shared Drive?

Comment: I made an application like that a number of years ago.   The only way you are going to get windows to be able to index them is to have them on the disk.   You could make a search method that just does a file.list on the api and add q paramater, thats the best i can think of.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone thinking along the same lines that I was with this issue, I ended up solving this by using a piece of great open source software from [voidtools.com](https://www.voidtools.com/) called `Everything` which allows you to index mapped network drive/NAS/Network shares.  This allows me to instantly locate files and folders by filename on Google shared drives.